# How to get get Uri of file in assets for argument in VideoView.setVideoURI()

Tags: android, uri, android-assets

I have been unsuccessful at generating a valid `android.net.Uri`, which references a mp4-file in my assets directory, which is required for the argument of `VideoView.setVideoURI(android.net.Uri uri)`.

Does anyone have a code fragment demonstrating how I can construct the Uri?

Answer (score 3):

`Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/path/to/your.mp4")` is a `Uri` to a file in your assets. Whether or not you can play a video from your assets, though, I can't say, as I have never tried it.

Comment: I have tried:vw.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/" + video.getFileName().toLowerCase())); and your example of vw.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("file://android_asset/" + video.getFileName().toLowerCase())); but simply get the message "Sorry this video cannot be played".

Comment: I can get a FileDescriptor for a file in assets and I know that a MediaPlayer has a setDataSource(FileDescriptor) so it seems like an unfortunate oversight that the VideoView does not provide that interface as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think other apps can access assets that are part of your .apk 
directly--you might have to copy it to the sdcard and have the PDF 
viewer access it from there

To copy a file from assets, you can use 
InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("UserGuide.pdf"); 
to get its content then write it into another file.